# Dynamically filtering a menu (ContextMenuStrip) in C# without recreating the menu?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, contextmenu, contextmenustrip

Is this possible?

I plan to have 10 menu items where these are going to have sub-menu items (1 level deep only). I want to be able to filter them when the user types into my `TextBox` control. I know I can filter items upon opening the menu for the first time, but I want to be able to continually filter it as the user types and hide categories on the fly when the category menu item has no subitems applicable for the current filter (by name filtering).

Any ideas?

Comment: could you possibly get at the compentlevel and check for it's type based on TextBox or by it's name..?

Comment: You always can disable non wanted menu entries. In my applications I did simply create the menu dynamically. Yes I do not have Designer support anymore but it was rather easy to do. The only thing that still bugs me is that the menu does pop up at least 10 or 20 pixels off the normal menu position.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I added a context menu strip (menuStrip1). To this I added the following:

```
File
   Exit

Edit
   Copy
   Paste
       Further Down

Help
   Arghhhh!
```

I then added a text box (FilterMenuText), and, on the OnTextChanged event, do the following:

```
    private void FilterMenuText_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        foreach (ToolStripMenuItem menuItem in menuStrip1.Items)
        {
            if (menuItem.DropDownItems.Count > 0)
            {
                bool matchFound = false;

                foreach (ToolStripMenuItem childMenuItem in menuItem.DropDownItems)
                {
                    if (childMenuItem.Text.ToUpper().Contains(FilterMenuText.Text.ToUpper()))
                    {
                        matchFound = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                menuItem.Visible = matchFound;

            }
        }

    }
```

This will hide and show the top level MenuItems as appropriate based on the content of the child menu items. If your menu has more than one level of drop down, put the foreach into a recursive function, like:

```
private void FilterMenuText_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    foreach (ToolStripMenuItem menuItem in menuStrip1.Items)
    {
        menuItem.Visible = MenuItemHasChildWithName(menuItem, FilterMenuText.Text);
    }

}


private bool MenuItemHasChildWithName(ToolStripMenuItem menuItem, string name)
{

    if (!menuItem.HasDropDownItems)
    {
        return false;
    }

    bool matchFound = false;

    foreach (ToolStripMenuItem childMenuItem in menuItem.DropDownItems)
    {

        if (childMenuItem.Text.ToUpper().Contains(name.ToUpper()))
        {
            matchFound = true;
            break;
        }

        if (childMenuItem.HasDropDownItems)
        {
            matchFound = MenuItemHasChildWithName(childMenuItem, name);

            if(matchFound) { break; }

        }

    }

    return matchFound;

}
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks good. Btw why do you use ToUpper but not ToLower?

Comment: Force of habit. Some people once mentioned that ToUpper is faster (and so it was used all over a project I was once a part of) but this isn't actually true. ToUpperInvariant() is optimised but ToUpper() and ToLower() are a matter of choice. Where possible, I use String.Compare, but in this instance you want to see if the letters you have typed are part of the name, so have used Contains instead. Strictly speaking, IndexOf might be a better choice for cluture invariant comparisons (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465121.aspx) but I was lazy.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I used for conditionaly showing menu items on a context menu. If you use the same menu and don't want to show it, you merely set each item in the same loop to true;

```
    private void dgViewData_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            if (dgViewData.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).Type != DataGridViewHitTestType.ColumnHeader)
            {
                foreach (ToolStripMenuItem menuItem in conMicImport.Items)
                {
                    menuItem.Visible = menuItem.Text.ToString().Contains("Add") == true ? false : true;
                }

                conMicImport.Show(dgViewData, e.Location);
                ctxtDG = dgViewData;
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the toolstrip object's Visible property to false when you don't want it to appear.

Answer (score 1):

for example purposes I have done this using a web forms application

```
foreach (Control c in Page.Form.Controls)
            {
                //Response.Write("WORD2" + c.GetType());
                if (c is Panel)
                {
                    foreach (Control p in c.Controls)
                    {
                        if (p is CheckBoxList)
                        {
                            foreach (ListItem li in ((CheckBoxList)p).Items)
                            {
                                li.Selected = false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thanks DJ, I am not sure what you mean with your comment, but I don't need to check for type though, just the menu items. I will do some experiments.

Comment: I mean if it's a TextBox the type or name of your TextBox control would be replaced with my example CheckListbox with Label ect... you can do the same check on a MenuItem. I was giving you this as a starting point.. the same thing will work on windows forms just replacing Page.Form.Controls with Form.Controls